# HSQLDB issue with Where condition

Tags: hsqldb

I am working in Eclipse SWT with HSQLDB 1.8.10. The query which I tried is:

`SELECT id, name, dept FROM students WHERE name='Sachin' OR name='Prakash' AND dept='ECE'`.

Ideally, the above query should fetch all the students in ECE dept with name either Sachin or Prakash. But the query does not considering the third condition i.e., it fetches the students from other departments also instead of only ECE. Moreover, if I queried as:

`SELECT id, name, dept FROM students WHERE name='Sachin' OR name='Prakash' AND dept='abcdef'`

Here i gave dept as 'abcdef' still it fetches the same records as before even though there is no such dept in the name 'abcdef'.

Actually,

1. How HSQLDB works with Where conditions?
2. Do we need to do something if we use both 'AND' and 'OR' condition in same query

I have tried google and Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any relevant answers. Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old version of HSQLDB. You should use the latest version 2.3.2.

With the old version, try to enclose the conditions in brackets and see if it works correctly

```
SELECT id, name, dept FROM students WHERE (name='Sachin' OR name='Prakash') AND dept='ECE'
```